# an ulam distance in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, combinatorics

I found quite a usefull box of tools in here : [library](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/BayesMallows/versions/0.3.0/topics/get_rank_distance) that I'd like to use in python but that is coded in R.

In particular I'd like to use the following method:

```
get_rank_distance(permutation1, permutation2, 'ulam')
```

`permutation1` and `permutation2` being two permutations over n elements.

I did not manage to find an existing equivalent in p\Python. Do you know if there is one and in which library I could find it.

FYI the ulam distance between two permutations p1 and p2 over the same number of elements, is the minimum number of operation sets needed to transform p1 in p2, the operation set being 1 deletion, any number of shift you want and 1 insertion of the element just deleted. You can see an exemple of it [here](https://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/Similarity/UlamDistance.html).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there is a python equivalent for that, but have you considered running R code in python using [rpy2](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/introduction.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the Ulam distances is defined as the number of items minus the length of the longest common subsequence of the two permutations, it should be straightforward to compute this with the `pylcs` package, available from [here](https://github.com/Meteorix/pylcs).

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a library, [this article](https://addi.ehu.es/bitstream/handle/10810/11241/tr14-4.pdf) gives you a formula.

Here is some python code which does it:

```py
def longest_increasing_lengths(perm):
    """
    >>> longest_increasing_lengths([2, 3, 1])
    [1, 2, 1]
    """
    result = [1]*len(perm)
    for j in range(len(perm)):
        for i in range(j):
            if perm[i] < perm[j] and result[i] >= result[j]:
                result[j] = result[i] + 1
    return result

def ulam_distance(pattern, disorder):
    """
    >>> ulam_distance([1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4,5,6])
    0 
    >>> ulam_distance([1,2,3,4,5,6], [2,5,3,1,4,6])
    2
    """
    perm = [pattern.index(x) for x in disorder]
    return len(perm) - max(longest_increasing_lengths(perm))
```